# What will be the expiry time, when we set SESSION_DRIVER / CACHE_DRIVER as redis in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, stackexchange.redis

Session lifetime is set as below

```
'lifetime' => 10080
```

Now I just want to set an expiry time when we set "**SESSION_DRIVER**" as Redis

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
```

If we set "**CACHE_DRIVER**" as Redis cache instead of file what will expire time or how can we set expire time for "**CACHE_DRIVER**"

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem we need to tell Laravel there are different Redis connections, one for Cache and one for Session.

First, navigate to `config/database`.php at the bottom of the file you'll see the settings for Redis and there will be a default connection. We need to add a new connection, using the same host, password and host but change the database number.

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

        'session' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 1,
        ],

    ],
```

Now we need to tell redis to use this connection as the session. Open up the `config/session.php` file and find the connection property, then change this to 'session'.

```
'connection' => 'session',
```